# anchor tag inside a repeater with runat = "server" acting strange

Tags: asp.net

I have following code inside my asp.net repeater inside itemtemplate.

```
<a runat = "server" href = "StoreCategory/testing.aspx">dsdsdsd</a>
```

Now, I would think that this link would point to mydomain.com/StoreCategory/testing.aspx (which it does if runat = "server" is not in there)

However, if I keep runat = "server" there, the link turns out to be mydomain.com/testing.aspx.  It drops StoreCategory! Why do you think it is doing that?

I figured out part of the problem, the reason is the current page is StoreCategory.aspx.  However, why only runat = "server" is getting confused and how to tell it not to get confused is beyond me, hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Hai,

Have you tried using asp:linkbutton with postbackUrl property

Use

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb" runat="server"  PostBackUrl="StoreCategory/testing.aspx" Text="dsdsdsd"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: but I want to use anchor tag, and I want to know the reason for this string behavior. If I this anchor tag outside of the repeater or if I do not use runat = "server", then everything seems fine.

Comment: I meant "strange behavior" by string behavior. type.

Answer (score 0):

Hai progtick,

Have a look at this it would help you [Is Adding runat="server" to HTML tags to get relative path in ASP.net an elegant solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400146/is-adding-runatserver-to-html-tags-to-get-relative-path-in-asp-net-an-elegant)

Comment: no, that link did not help me a bit. I am setting my base element to be root folder's location already.